# Emails are marked as coming from the recipient "GMAIL"

Tags: gmail

I have a person's email address saved in my contacts, but when they send me an email, it comes up with the name "GMAIL".

This seems to have just changed as previous emails came through with the proper name on them.

Comment: Is it just that one contact? What happens if you create a new message to send to them?

Answer (score 1):

Use "show original" from the message menu. I'll bet you'll find a line in the message headers like

```
From: "GMAIL" <your-contact@example.net>
```

Why Gmail isn't picking up the name you've got for them in your Google Contacts, I don't know. Perhaps there is a very slight difference in the email address.